# Bevel modifier geometry issue

Tags: geometry, bevel

I'm having some difficulties with the bevel modifier in blender.

I am trying to bevel edges using a vertex group. In the picture is the geometry with the vertex group selected.

[image: Before modifier]

When applying the bevel modifier the geometry looks like this.

[image: After modifier]

As you can see, the bevel modifier causes an issue with my geometry. I believe this is caused because of the bottom left vert of the selected face.

How can i fix the bevel to not mess up my geometry? preferably non destructive.

Regards,

UPDATE,

maybe it was not clear what i was trying to to. In the picture below, the red lines are the edges I'm trying to bevel. 
As you can see the bevel itself is OK, except some geometry issues are happening at the red arrow. I'm trying to find out how to fix this. If I apply the bevel i can manually fix the affected vertices, but I'm looking for something non destructive.
[image: After modifier]

Comment: That seem to be a general problem with beveling one edge of an L-shapes. The bevel tool in edit mode has the same output.

Comment: It's unclear which edges you want to bevel, you have an internal vertex selected on the top face. could you mark out which edges you want to be rounded?

Comment: what shape are you trying to achieve? Also maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have updated my question, hopefully it is a bit clearer now.

Comment: you might want to use the option weight of the bevel modifier, and set the bevel weight of the edges that you don't want to split to much to a low amount.